# conditionally render onPress for TouchableHighlight

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to conditionally render an `onPress`, if the description prop is `undefined`, I do want want any `onPress` functionality. My onPress fires regardless, how can I remove it if the description is undefined

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._onPressButton = this._onPressButton.bind(this);
}

_onPressButton(event) {
    Alert.alert(event.description);
}

render() {
    const { start, end, summary, description } = this.props;

    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => {
                description == "" ? null : this._onPressButton;
            }}

        >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like below or disable

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._onPressButton = this._onPressButton.bind(this);
}

_onPressButton(event) {
    Alert.alert(event.description);
}

render() {
    const { start, end, summary, description } = this.props;

    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => {
                description == "" ? { } : this._onPressButton; // You can add { } instead of null
            }}
           disabled={description === ""} // Or you can just disabled conditionally 

        >
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition you are using will always return `false` as an empty string is not undefined :

```js
console.log(undefined == "")
```

This behavior is quite weird as your function is not even returned in your arrow function.

The following should do the trick by putting a function that does not do anything :

```
onPress={description ? this._onPressButton : x => {} }
```

This may also work with an inline if :

```
onPress={description && this._onPressButton }
```